# javascript regex seems to be ignoring anchor

Tags: javascript, regex, string, url, hostname

I am trying to make a javascript bookmarklet that takes the current page url, modifies the domain to a different one, then opens that in a new tab.

for example, given the url:

`https://prod.abc.com/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij`

I want to run the bookmarklet and have it open

`https://dev.abc-1-de.net/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij`

This is my current code

```
javascript:(function() {window.open(window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/.*?abc.com\//, 'https://dev.abc-1-de.net/'), '_blank');})()
```

When I run

```
window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/.*?abc.com\//, 'https://dev.abc-1-de.net/')
```

I get the url I'm expecting. However, when I run the whole thing together, the new tab that opens is directed to

`https://prod.abc.com/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/https://dev.abc-1-de.net/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij`.

To me, this seems like the regex is ignoring my `^` anchor for some reason, but I have no idea why that would be happening only when it is passed into `window.open`.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the regular expression you're using. The .*? is matching any character, including forward slashes, so it's matching beyond the domain part of the URL. You can modify the regular expression to only match up until the first forward slash after the domain like this: `/^https:\/\/[^\/]+\/(.*)$/
`

Comment: To me this more looks like that the `window.open()` somehow sees this as a relative instead of an absolute URL and hence adds it up. Trying to actually reproduce to see if I can come up with a reasonable reason why it would thing that

Comment: One does not even need a regex because one could utilize [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) on that matter. Example ... `const url = new URL("https://prod.abc.com/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij"); url.hostname = 'dev.abc-1-de.net'; console.log(String(url));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, the issue was a typo in the replacement url I was giving, as well as in the way that window.open works. The replacement url I was giving in my unobfuscated code had the typo `https//:` instead of `https:`.

This made the window.open function think this was a relative url instead of an absolute, and so it was appending it instead of properly redirecting.

Answer (score 1):

Running this seems to work, as you said:

```js
var oldUrl = "https://prod.abc.com/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij";
var newUrl = oldUrl.replace(/^https:\/\/.*?abc.com\//, 'https://dev.abc-1-de.net/');

console.log(newUrl)
```

The console prints out `https://dev.abc-1-de.net/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij` as you expect it to.

When I run this code:

```js
window.open("https://dev.abc-1-de.net/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij", "_blank")
```

I am just redirected to a blank window in a new tab.  However setting `window.location.href` does redirect, but it does not open in a new window

```js
window.location.href = "https://dev.abc-1-de.net/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij";
```

So your full code would be

```js
javascript:(function() {
  window.location.href = window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/.*?abc.com\//, 'https://dev.abc-1-de.net/');
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working correctly for me.I made a new bookmark with the code `javascript:(function() {window.open(window.location.toString().replace(/^https:\/\/.*?.com\//, 'https://dev.abc-1-de.net/'), '_blank');})()`

I removed the `abc` from the regex and now this bookmark will work for all domains. It essentially replaces the the domain with `dev.abc-1-de.net`

Answer (score 0):

One does not even need a regex because one could utilize [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) on that matter. Example ...

```js
const url =
  new URL("https://prod.abc.com/lorum/a-1234/b/c.d/e/1234#fg:hij");

url.hostname = 'dev.abc-1-de.net';

console.log(
  url.href
);
console.log(
  String(url)
);
```